# htaccess redirect www to non www not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've got the following code in my htaccess file to redirect www to non www, which works fine on the homepage, but any other page it still keeps the www in the URL..

```
# REDIRECT WWW TO NON WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blackseriescampertrailers\.com\.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/$1 [L,R=301]
```

http://www.blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/ will go to http://blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/ which is working as expected, however http://www.blackseriescampertrailers.com.au/caravans.html remains the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This should be the very first Rule in your htaccess.

Comment: It is the first rule in my file